# KevinCookieCompany: .gitignore is not ignoring .txt file on Mac

Tags: git, macos, terminal, gitignore

**Created .gitignore in TextEdit and saved as plain text document.**

(hashtag) ignore all .txt files

*.txt

**When I check git status in terminal the file Employee Salaries.txt still shows up.**
On branch main

No commits yet

Untracked files:
(use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)
.DS_Store
.gitignore.txt
Employee Salaries.txt
KCC Logo.png
index.htm
secret recipe.htm

**[Photo of how it looks]**(https://i.stack.imgur.com/feniL.png)
**The files are all in red and not commited.**

**Thought maybe .gitignore file needed another format. Changed it from a .txt file to a .rtf file. Did not make a difference. In Finder it shows as .gitignore**
**[Photo of how its saved]**[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqRWP.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoveflow. As a general rule to formulate questions: prefer copy pasting *text* rather than posting *screen captures* (unlike pictures, text can be searched, copied and indexed). As far as formatting goes: to format code, you can click on the `{}` button of the editor, or surround your code block with three backticks (\`\`\`), which will allow to make a clear distinction between terminal output and text for your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename `.gitignore.rtf` to just `.gitignore`.

Comment: In Finder it is saved as .gitignore but shows up as .gitignore.rtf in the Terminal.

Comment: I don't know what "Finder" is, but if terminal shows the name as `.gitignore.rtf`, then that is the filename and you need to change it.

Comment: Thank you 1615903 for pointing out the problem is with the formatting. Solution for me was the following. Open TextEdit. Format > Make Plain Text. Save and uncheck If no extension is provided, use “.txt”.

Answer (score 0):

I found this video very useful to create a `.gitignore` without any further extension like `.rtf` or `.txt`: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6wQ28h-MmE&t=132s

In short, you can go to Terminal and type `touch .gitignore` (it creates a file), then `open .gitignore` (it opens .gitignore file).

Now you can type and then close the file:

```
# ignore all .txt files
*.txt
```

When you type `git status`, you see that it works.

If you would need to add or remove something in `.gitignore`, type `open .gitignore`.